# How to add custom drop down on every product details page in magento 1.9

Tags: magento, magento-1.9

I have added Yes/No field in admin product create page.

Now I want to show one dropdown on frontend product listing page based on that admin yes/no field.

I want to do this programmatically.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Open your **view.phtml** template: `app/design/frontend/VENDOR/THEME/template/catalog/product/view.phtml`

and place this code where u want to show your Dropdown:

```php
<?php if ($_product->getAttributeText('ATTRIBUTE_NAME') == "Yes"): ?>
  <select>
    <option value="1">Option one</option>
    <option value="2">Option two</option>
    <option value="3">Option three</option>
  </select>
<?php endif; ?>
```

Comment: Thanks!!! this is working..but I want to save this field. can we add attribute field to save..

Comment: What exactly do you mean? You want to save the value from the dropdown on your product page?

Comment: Yes. same like we add custom options to product.

Comment: I think you have to make a custom module that saves the value, something like this: [link](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/70355/add-to-cart-with-custom-option)